# Pytorch how to multiply tensors of variable size except the first dimention

Tags: python, matrix, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have one tensor which is `A = 40x1`.

i need to multiply this one with 3 other tensors: `B = 40x100x384, C = 40x10, D=40x10`.

for example in tensor `B`, we got 40 `100x384` matrixes and i need each one of these matrixes to be multiplied with its corresponding element from `A`

what is the best way to do this in pytorch? Suppose that we could have more matrixes like B,C,D they will always be in the style `40xKxL` or `40xJ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to multiply every i-th matrix `K x L` by the corresponding i-th scalar in `A`.

One possible way is:

```
(A * B.view(len(A), -1)).view(B.shape)
```

Or you can use the power of [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html):

```
A = A.reshape(len(A), 1, 1)
# now A is (40, 1, 1) and you can do
A*B
A*C
A*D
```

essentially each trailing dimension equal to 1 in `A` is stretched and copied to match the other matrix.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post, I meant that the other matrixes could also be `40xJ` not all of them have the same style (`40xKxL`)